# How do I insert multiple rows from a POST

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have a View that contains n number of input fields (the number will vary based on different criteria). the value of each input field needs to be inserted in the database in their own row.
My problem is that only the first input field is inserted into the database. The controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,MemberId,Rated,Rating")] Rating rating)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Ratings.Add(rating);
                    db.SaveChanges();                  
                }
```

The value of MemberId is the same for each row, but Rated and Rating will be different.

My model looks like this:

```
[Table("Rating")]
    public partial class Rating
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? MemberId { get; set; }

        public int Rated { get; set; }

        [Column("Rating")]
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        public virtual TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
    }
```

The view looks like this:

```
@model Teamer.Models.Rating

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Rating</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @{
                int count = 0;

                foreach (var item in ViewBag.MemberId)
                {
                    string rater = Request.Cookies["rater"]["name"].ToString();
                    string raterId = Request.Cookies["rater"]["raterId"];

                    if (item.Name.ToLower() != rater.ToLower())
                    {
                        if (ViewBag.raterId != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var raterid in ViewBag.raterId)
                            {
                                <input type="hidden" name="MemberId" value="@raterid" />
                            }
                        }
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="@item.Name">@item.Name</label>
                            <input type="number" name="Rating-@count" value="0" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="Rated" value="@item.Id" />
                        </div>  
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="count" value="@count" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I'm guessing, I need to loop through the values one by one, but I can't get that to work, so maybe I'm way off on that.

**EDIT**

OK, so I got it working now with at simple, although maybe a bit ugly, solution.
My controller now looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Rating rating)
        {
            int count = int.Parse(Request.Form["count"]);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string test = Request.Form["MemberId"];
                rating.MemberId = int.Parse(test);
                rating.Rated = int.Parse(Request.Form["Rated-" + i]);
                rating.Rating1 = int.Parse(Request.Form["Rating1-" + i]);
                db.Ratings.Add(rating);

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

And my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Rating</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            int count = 0;
            string raterId = Request.Cookies["rater"]["raterId"];
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.MemberId)
            {
                string rater = Request.Cookies["rater"]["name"].ToString();


                if (item.Name.ToLower() != rater.ToLower())
                {

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="@item.Name">@item.Name</label>
                        <input type="number" name="Rating1-@count" value="0" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="Rated-@count" value="@item.Id" />
                    </div>

                    count++;
                }

            }
        }
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MemberId" value="@raterId" />

    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="@count" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

It's simple enough, but I get the feeling there's a better, cleaner way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you also post the view? 
Have you tried  as List<Rating>? Only Rating will return just first element of the form.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy Adding List<Rating> gives an error on db.Ratings.Add(rating); - "Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.generics.List...' to 'Rate.Models.Rating'

Comment: @Lasserh what happened when you tried looping through, can you show that code please?

Comment: @ DanChase When I debug it seems my Request.Form's contain lists. When I try to update e.g. rating.Rated i get an 'Input string was not in a correct format'-error - which makes sense, I think, as it's not just one int, but a whole list of them.
I'm really at a loss as to how I need to handle the inputs to separate them and treat them individually.

Comment: Any luck on this @Lasserh?

Comment: Well, @tvdias, I got it working with the edit above. But it seems a bit clumbsy, so I was hoping someone could help cleaning it up just a bit. But it IS working now, so...

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of problems, but it the end, you're not posting what is expected by your controller. Your controller is expecting to get a `Rating` (so Id, MemberId, Rated, and Rating), but you're actually posting something like

```
MemberId=raterId (repeated by as many ViewBag.raterId you have)
Rating-0=0
Rated=memberX_Id
Rating-1=0
Rated=memberY_Id
Rating-2=0
Rated=memberZ_Id
(...)
Rating-n=0
Rated=memberM_Id
count=(n+1)
```

If you check your posted data, you should have only MemberId and Rated filled.

In order to achieve what you want, you'll need to have a list of `Rating` or a different structure on your controller side. Bear in mind, if you want to post an array, it should be something like

```
MemberId[0]=
Rated[0]=
Rating[0]=
MemberId[1]=
Rated[1]=
Rating[1]=
(...)
MemberId[n]=
Rated[n]=
Rating[n]=
```

Also, note that MemberId and Rated get overridden in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

The Client is sending an array to controller, binding modification is required. The controller should accept an array or collection of `Rating`:

```
   public ActionResult Create(Icollection<Rating> ratings)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
        //saving...              
       }
    }
```

Update:
As one of the good practices, It is better to work with DTO instead of your Database Entity, you might want to create a `RatingDto` Class:

```
  public partial class RatingDto
  {
      public int MemberId { get; set; }

      public int Rate { get; set; }
  }
```

And not to forget changing View:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
   <input type="hidden" name="MemberId" value="@raterId" />
   <input type="number" name="Rate" value="0" />
 </div>
```

Binding in Asp.net MVC works like so, associate html `name` attribute to `property` name in C# code.
It`s rather complicated to know what another programmer have expected from his code to do but the **Key** points are:

- Instead of ViewBags and Cookies use `Model`
- Pay attention to how Binding works
- Replace Entity with Dto
- Use debugger (Google Chrome,Firefox, etc) to check what do you send
  to browser

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for input. This results in ratings being null - so nothing inserted.

Comment: @Lasserh, sepehr ir right to point you out to the "list" on the controller side, but it's not enough. In order to post arrays/collections you should also update your front end. Please check my answer for more details on how to post arrays, but bear in mind there are other issues in your code.